# Get disk informations without using WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm using check_mk as monitoring solution and I disabled WMI service cause it create timeout when check_mk query for information.

`Get-WmiObject` / `Get-Disk` / `Get-PSDrive` use WMI service to get information and I would like to get disk information like total space, used space etc without using WMI beacause I can't.

Do you know any workaround do to that?

Comment: PInvoke the win32 API? Write your own c#/c++ app that generates consumable output like json,xml,csv, etc.

Comment: Re-enable the WMI service and fix whatever problem is causing the timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR -

```
(echo select disk=0 & echo list partition & (for /l %A in (1,1,10) do @echo select disk=next &@echo list partition)) | diskpart | findstr /i /v /r "^$ > microsoft ^reached ^select ^there ^the\ start"
```

## Details -

The 'diskpart.exe' command can get you what you want.  It requires admin rights, but since you mentioned disabling services, that didn't sound like an issue.

Rather than interacting with DISKPART's unique menu system, this example will blindly request the list of partitions on the first 11 disks (and filter away unnecessary lines..).  Should be enough. 
 :-)

#### Cmd:

```
(echo select disk=0 & echo list partition & (for /l %A in (1,1,10) do @echo select disk=next &@echo list partition)) | diskpart | findstr /i /v /r "^$ > microsoft ^reached ^select ^there ^the\ start"
```

#### Output From My Live System:

```
Disk 0 is now the selected disk.
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary           1863 GB  1024 KB
Disk 1 is now the selected disk.
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            350 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            270 GB   351 MB
  Partition 3    Recovery           845 MB   271 GB
  Partition 4    Primary            204 GB   272 GB
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            931 GB  1024 KB
```